# cambiar las imagenes en movil, carrusel de bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Hola estoy usando el carrusel de bootstrap 5 y quiero cambiar las imagenes en movil por otras, para que se vean mejor, estoy usando css para ello, desconozco si bootstrap tiene una forma de hacerlo solo a traves de clases, si saben otra forma de hacerlo para no crear otro slider en movil seria genial, gracias

codigo HTML:

```
   <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark 
  slide" data-bs- 
  ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" 
 data-bs-slide-to="0" 
  class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1">. 
 </button>
  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" 
 data-bs-slide-to="1" 
  aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" 
 data-bs-slide-to="2" 
 aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
 </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
     <img src="/../wp-content/uploads/2022/06/multiethnic- 
  business-partners-having- 
   meeting-at-ta-2021-08-29-21-21-00-utc-Baja-768x513-1.jpg" 
   class="d-block w-100" 
  alt="...">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h1 class="h1">Bienvenido</h1>
      <h2>Lanzamos nuestro Informe de Sostenibilidad 2021</h2>
      <button class="btn btn-primary boton-slider">Conocer 
    más</button> 
    </div>
    </div>
   <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
    <img src="/../wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Banner-Mes-del- 
    Orgullo-Escritorio.gif" 
    class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h5>Second slide label</h5>
      <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second 
    slide.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="carousel-item">
     <img src="../wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Banner-Mes-del- 
  Orgullo-Escritorio.gif" 
  class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h5>Third slide label</h5>
      <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third 
  slide.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

codigo CSS para llamar a otra imagen en movil, en este caso reemplazaria a las 3 que estan en desktop, le añadi el !important para ver si obligaba a sobreescribir pero no funcionó

```
.carousel-item img{
background-image: url(/../wp-content/uploads/2022/06/google- 
icone-symbole-logo-png- 
e1655161724214.png) !important;
}
```

Comment: Sobre tu último bloque CSS: ¿Cómo aplicas esa regla en móviles? ¿Estás usando media queries?

Comment: Hola, si estoy usando media query

Comment: Por favor, haz clic en [edit] tu pregunta y agrega un [example] en el que muestres cómo estás implementando las media queries